# Android NetworkInfo.State differences

Tags: android

I've been using the class [NetworkInfo.State](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.State.html) to know the status of the internet connection in my device, I wondered what exactly is the difference between **NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED** and **NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING**?

or between **NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTING** and **NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED**

The official documentation does not say much about it.

In several examples use both, for example

```
if (conMgr.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED
|| conMgr.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING) {
  //something.....
}
```

But I think there are two states for something in particular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING** denotes if the network state is currently setting up data connection(like scanning, authenticating stuffs).

**NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED** Voila! The network has successfully connected to a certain network and data traffic is now available.

**NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTING** is simply meaning that the data connection is now getting disconnected.

and **NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED** means network is idle or unavailable or simply put, disconnected.